# Android opencv imread function throwing null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

I am currently developing a simple android app for practice that takes a photography use the camera application, turns it into grayscale and saves it to device storage. For image processing I am using opencv for android. Following is the snippet which is responsible for turning the image into grayscale before saving it.

```
   try{
      File imageFile=new File(puri.getPath());  
      Mat m = Highgui.imread(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
      Imgproc.cvtColor(m, m, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
      imageFile.delete();
      Highgui.imwrite(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(),m);
     }
     catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
    }
```

All works well but when imread is called it throws a null pointer exception. I have the OpenCV SDK manager installed on my device and all other opencv samples are running flawlessly.

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated thanks

Comment: yes but it should not

Comment: my app invokes the camera application from the camera application I get an image URI which is then used to generate imageFile object. This happens in the following line. 

File imageFile=new File(puri.getPath);

Here puri is the photo URI of the image taken by the camera application

Comment: Split `Mat m = Highgui.imread(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());` to 2 lines: `final String filePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();` and  `Split Mat m = Highgui.imread(filePath);`. Where the NPE happens now? if at `imageFile.getAbsolutePath()` then your `File` can't be built using `purl`. So check what `purt` contains ising `Log.d()`

Comment: puri is image file URI